# Filter selection by array without losing order d3js

Tags: arrays, sorting, d3.js, graph

I'm newbie in d3js and I want to create an animation between two nodes in a graph represented by circles.

I have calculated the shortest path between start and end nodes using the function path. It returns an array of circle's ids that represent the path that you must follow from source (start) to target(end). 
Something like this: 23, 24, 37, 29, 30.

```
var ruta = path(data.pred, start, end);
```

After that I used the filter function to select the nodes (circles) that forms the shortest path between start and end.

```
var selection = svg.selectAll('circle').filter(function(d){ return ruta.indexOf(d.index.toString()) >- 1;});
```

Then, I tried to animate the path using this simple transition, changing the size of circles one by one.

```
                       selection.transition()
                                .delay(function(d,i) { return i/ len * enter_duration;})
                                .style("opacity",1.0)
                                .attr("r", 10.0)
                                .each("end",function() { 
                                    d3.select(this).       
                                        transition()
                                        .delay(function(d,i) { return i/ len * enter_duration;})
                                        .attr("r",7)
                                        .style("opacity",0.7);            
                                });
```

The problem is that the filter selection losses the original order of nodes.

Example:

Original path: 23, 24, 37, 29, 30.
Selection order: 23, 24, **29, 30, 37.**

How can I reorder the selection objects based on the original array?

Comment: Use the `.sort()` function. This uses data bound to the elements, so I would recommend that you bind a data structure that you can infer the order from.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, this function works like a magic key :)
            `var sortItems = function (a, b) { 
                value_a = ruta.indexOf(a.id.toString());
                value_b = ruta.indexOf(b.id.toString())
                return value_a - value_b ;
            };
`.

Comment: Ok, so using that with `.sort()` solves the problem for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `.sort()` as @LarsKotthoff suggested. This is my comparator function, I made the original array (ruta) global and then I used index position in ruta to sorting de selection array.

```
sortItems = function (a, b) { 
  value_a = ruta.indexOf(a.id.toString());
  value_b = ruta.indexOf(b.id.toString())
  return value_a - value_b ;
};
```

And this is the code to sorting the selection

```
selection
  **.sort(sortItems)**
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d,i) { return i/ len * enter_duration;})
  .style("opacity",1.0)
  .attr("r", 10.0)
  .each("end",function() { 
    d3.select(this) 
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d,i) { return i/ len * enter_duration;})
        .attr("r",7)
        .style("opacity",0.7);            
  });
```